# Can you record audio on the iPhone using PhoneGap?

Tags: iphone, audio, cordova

Is it possible to record audio on the iPhone using the PhoneGap package? And if so, are there any examples of this?

Comment: Why does it belong on Superuser I wonder? PhoneGap is one of those silly development toolchains that people who don't want to learn Objective-C use to create iPhone apps (and conversely, apps for Android, etc)

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was an iPhone app.

Answer (score 4):

http://wiki.phonegap.com/iPhone%3A-Record-and-Playback-Audio

Comment: I saw that earlier, but everyone's reply to that post said that they couldn't get it working.

Comment: I just tested this code directly from the link above and it works on my iphone 4

Answer (score 0):

According to the [project site](http://wiki.phonegap.com/Roadmap): "We are working on it". Guess this means no.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me on iOS now:

http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_media_media.md.html#media.startRecord

Audio quality is fairly mediocre.